# Ruby Shoes App packaged for Windows doesn't display images

Tags: ruby, windows, image, shoes

When I package my Shoes App for Windows images doesn't work. I have this very simple app (min_test.rb):

```
Shoes.app() 
{ 
  background "bg.jpg"
}
```

Which works fine if I run it through Shoes, but when I package it with Shoes so that I get a standalone .exe file the images doesn't load. Inside the folder these are the contents:

```
min_test.rb
bg.jpg
min_test.exe (after packaging)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Shoes3.3.1, indeed, on linux too.
console (alt-/) saying "couldn't find tmp.....bg.jpg" ?
(background or image)
could you file a bug report, please : https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3/issues

EDIT: Sorry, wait
if Shoes3.3.1 !
you have to first make a shy then an exe and the resulting exe will be outside of the directory where your script and image is.
follow this : https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3/wiki/Packaging
(note: tested on linux and on Windows)

Comment: Ah, your edit works, however it makes me run into the next problem. When doing it like that it seems all images gets packaged into the .exe. My program will be downloading images from the web so I can't pre-package my images. If I follow your edit and don't have the images in the folder when I package to .exe none of the images are shown, even if I move the .exe to a folder where the images are in afterwards. Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I'll create a separate question for this issue since the original issue is now solved. Thanks!